# search issue by custom field in redmine

Tags: ruby, redmine, redmine-api

I have a list of issues which I want to search by email. Currently the email custom field id is 4. But when I use this request:
`GET http://redmine.mysite.com/issues.json?cf_4=somebody@gmail.com`
I am getting an array containing all issues with default limit(25). Is there a way I can search issues by email?
I am using Redmine REST API for Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing looks correct. Make sure *Used as filter* in the custom field's settings is checked.

If that is the case, the log of this request and your Redmine version would be of interest.